# Url not showing in bibliography

Tags: urls, bibliographystyle

I have a problem with the bibliography. I tried using the bibliography style "plain": I get the citations in square brackets, but the url is not showing. However, if I use the style "plainurl", it will show the url, but the citations are in round brackets.

How can I get the citations in square brackets and the url showing in the bibliography at the same time?

Comment: Did you try with `biblatex`?

Answer (score 1):

The `plain` bibliography style has been around, more or less unchanged, since the early 1980s. As such, it and its fellow original BibTeX styles (`unsrt`, `abbrv`, `apalike`, `ieeetr` and maybe a few others) predate the creation of the world wide web and, by implication, the notion that one could employ a URL string to express a document's online whereabouts. Your bib entry may provide a field called `url`, but the `plain` style simply ignores it since it doesn't know what to do with this piece of information.

What to do? I suggest you (a) load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `numbers` (to create numeric-style citation call-outs) and (b) employ the `plainnat` bibliography style. Compared with `plain`, the main user-relevant changes in `plainnat` are the recognition of the fields `url`, `doi`, and `eid`.

After changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, be sure to run a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.